# CakePHP 3.0 Blog Tutorial Error: The view for UsersController::index() was not found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So I am running into a CakePHP 3.0 error and might have skipped a few steps accidentally in the Blog tutorial. I don't want to start all over because this is work related. Right now I have the users/add and the login working but I don't have the users view working. Attached is a screenshot of the error message:

[image: Error Message]

Is there a way I can create a users/index.ctp file and what code would I put into it? If not, how do I fix an error like this without starting all over?

Update: I fixed this error but ran into a new error that has to do with the helper, this can be seen here [new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOI1I.png)

Update: I changed line 16 in the Controller/UserControllers file and found out it was a paginator error:

```
$this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users->find('all')));
```

I got help from someone in the Cake Slack PHP forum

Comment: Your error itself is an answer, go to respective folder location just as mentioned in error and make index.ctp file.

Comment: You can optionally have the file auto generated using the [bake utility](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html), for example 'bin/cake bake template users'

Comment: I know where to create the index.ctp file but don't know what code I will need to put in it and the Cake Blog tutorial only shows code for other index.ctp files not the user one

Comment: I fixed the error but ran into a new one that I had a problem debugging and trying to fix with the bake commands

Answer (score 0):

As it states [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#creating-all-user-related-code) in the tutorial you're following:

> In the same way we created the views for our articles by using the
>   code generation tool, we can implement the user views. For the purpose
>   of this tutorial, we will show just the add.ctp:

So if you wanted to follow along with the tutorial you'd have to create User views in the same way you did for Articles [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#creating-article-views)

Comment: Those views are already created for the controllers, I can not find the index.ctp one which is different

Comment: I fixed the error but ran into a new one that I had a problem debugging and trying to fix with the bake commands